# PHP regular expression - match from start and end of string

Tags: php, regex

I used an online regular expression (regex) tester to build a simple regex, however using PHP's [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) it's giving an unknown modifier for `$`.

Here is the regex:

```
if (preg_match('/(^Keyword1/$|^Keyword2/$)/', $input, $matches))
```

I'm trying to check if `$input` equals either Keyword1/ or Keyword2/ (exact match). I know I can easily do this with "if ($input == 'Keyword1/')", however I'd rather have a few lines of regex vs. a dozen *if* statements in the code.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Note, you could also use an array of allowed keywords and `in_array`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` inside the regex, because `/` is also being used as delimiter:

```
if (preg_match('/(^Keyword1\/$|^Keyword2\/$)/', $input, $matches))
                           ^            ^
```

Alternatively, use a different delimiter:

```
if (preg_match('~(^Keyword1/$|^Keyword2/$)~', $input, $matches))
                ^                         ^
```

Since both your sub-regexs have common anchors, you can simplify your regex as:

```
 if (preg_match('~^(Keyword1|Keyword2)/$~', $input, $matches))
```

**Why the warning in your regex?**

```
'/(^Keyword1/$|^Keyword2/$)/'
```

Since you are using `/` as delimiter, the second `/` in your regex makes PHP think it is the end of your regex. Now PHP accepts regex modifiers like `s`, `m`, `i` after the closing delimiter. But in your case, PHP sees a `$` after the closing delimiter. Since `$` is not a valid modifier you get the warning:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '$' in ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've used the `/` inside your regex without escaping it.

Here's what you're looking for, but maybe a little better:

```
'/^(Keyword1|Keyword2)\\/$/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
preg_match('/^Keyword[1-2]\/$/', $input, $matches)
```

Comment: `[12]` would do the same, but I'm going to assume that "keyword1" is just an example, and not the *actual* string he's looking for.